# What is the proper term for a moderate-size artificial stone-clad elevation?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Paris, as you walk along the Quai Francois Mitterrand, one option is to go down the steps to the paved riverside pedestrian path (where cars are allowed only in movies).

It is a quaint little space between the two bridges (the Pont Neuf and the Pont de Beaux Arts).

You can continue along the edge or you could opt for climbing the **stone-clad elevation with the sloping sides** (alternatively, you can walk along the bottom of the elevation and run up those steps in the middle), and sit on the bench in the shadow of the tree.
In the photo, there are two red arrows pointing at the elevation.

Is there a proper term for this kind of ... structure, or whatever it is? Something like an "urban hillock" or some such? Or something more architectural-sounding?
[image]

Comment: Some subtype of a kerb, perhaps?

Comment: It looks like a low retaining wall, whatever it’s made of.

Comment: Perhaps a (wingwall)[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing_wall].

Answer (score 7):

This is an *embankment*.

> ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/embankment)) an artificial slope made of earth and/or stones:
> a river/road/railway embankment

The particular one shown by the Seine is but one among many possibilities along the same principle.

You will find [here](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=embankment,images&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO2PSy7fDwAhXfA2MBHXGBB2EQjJkEegQIBhAB&biw=1920&bih=1005) a great variety of constructions of that type.

[image]

[image]

A69-Haltwhistle-highway-embankment-western-end

[image]

Embankments

Comment: Plus one, but no dice: an embankment's main function is to hold back water. In this case it would be, not just the hillock, but the entire structure, including the riverfront path and the quai above.


a bank, mound, dike, or the like, raised to hold back water, carry a roadway, etc.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make here is this. The elevation is built ON TOP of the embankment. It is most certainly part of it, but it can also be viewed as a separate item.

Comment: @Ricky Apparently, this is not so, that is, not just for holding back water. Also you can have several levels, and each is called an embankment. But take a look at the pictures  from the link, there is a greater  variety).

Comment: Okay, I'm beginning to warm up to the term. However, since the thing in the photo serves no immediately apparent purpose, wouldn't it be "a decorative embankment"?

Comment: @Ricky That is a question; is there a primary purpose? if so, maybe it's better to say "decorated embankment", although it is still possible to say "decorative embankment", meaning that the embankment has an attractive aspect but is not merely decorative. It is difficult for me to conceive an embankment that would be only decorative.

Comment: Maybe it's a terrace.

Comment: @Ricky As you can see [here](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=terrace,image&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjln729__DwAhUp5eAKHUPtAY4QjJkEegQIBhAB&biw=1920&bih=1005), a terrace is almost always a horizontal surface, although there is a case of "stair terrace" in that lot that is comparable to a series of embankments.

Comment: Uh ... terrace agriculture? ...

Comment: @Ricky Here, again, a striking similarity: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=stair+terrace

Comment: @Ricky a terrace can be a single flat area (such a dwelling's patio) or a series of them created by embankments.

Comment: Embankments can be, but are not solely, for the purpose of retaining water. They can also be used for other purposes, such as with highways and railroads.